# how to integrate bootstrap-carousel in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to  integrate bootstrap-carousel in my WordPress site. I do`

```
                 <div class="carousel-inner">
                <? $carousel_posts = get_posts('category=12&showposts=3');
                    foreach ($carousel_posts as $post) :
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    ?>

                   <div class="item">
                     <div class="carousel-caption">
                       <h3 class="hidden-xs"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                       <p class="hidden-xs"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                     </div>
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?>

                   </div>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
                 </div>

                 <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                 </a>

                 <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                 </a>
               </div>`
```

but carousel doesn't work. content and title of posts are shown but picture no! Why?

Comment: Is this all of your code specifically for the carousel because this is incomplete for it to work. If you have more please post all of it.

Comment: Also, can you post your resulting html

Comment: Oh, i've forgotten to add parent container for carousel here. ` <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide container" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel"></div>`

Comment: This <?php the_post_thumbnail('full');?> goes under div class="item"